# CSS Semi circle which can be changed by percentage

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I would like to create two semi circles with CSS: the top one, which would start at the top of the gray semi-circle and extend all the way down to the bottom, which would vary based on a percentage given. Here is what I have so far:

```css
#cpoints {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.rotated-half-circle {
  /* Create the circle */
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  border: 13px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /* Halve the circle */
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  /* Rotate the circle */
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.rotated-half-circle-party {
  /* Create the circle */
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  border: 18px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /* Halve the circle */
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  /* Rotate the circle */
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
.righta {
  margin-left: auto; 
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav id="sidebar" class="sidebar close"></nav>
<section  class="home">
    <div id="cpoints">
      <div class="h-26 grid grid-cols-3 gap-4 content-center">
        <div>
          <div class="herotext">
            <h4 class="divisionof">The federal division of</h4>
            <h1 class="seattitle" id="title"><?php echo $seat2;?></h1>
            <h2 class="state" id="state"><?php echo $state[0];?></h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div></div>
        <div class="place-self-center">
          <div>
            <div class="rotated-half-circle absolute" style="right: 15%;"></div>
            <div class="rotated-half-circle-party absolute" style="right: 15%;"></div>

            <p class="relative pt-5 pb-10 bd-white" style="bottom: -42px; right:-5%; background-color: white;"> 0.0% swing to XXX</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <hr>
      <p><b>Population</b>: <span id="population"><?php echo $population[0];?></span>   <b>Classification</b>: <?php echo $classification[0];?></p>
    </div>
</section>
</body>
```

That creates this (as a side-note, if anyone has an idea of how to better align the items that would be appreciated):

[image]

This is what I am aiming for:

[image]

I tried a bunch of different variations but I just don't know how I can vary the red one by a percentage.

Edit: I am using Tailwind CSS if that helps; not entirely – just started using it recently.

Comment: Are you using Tailwind CSS?

Comment: @showdev yes sorry should have clarified that